# Problemas con Google-Maps en Drupal 7.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, drupal

Estoy trabajando con una platilla en `drupal` en la cual necesito colocar un mapa de `google maps`, instale los modulos de gmap y otros que se necesitan para poder colocar los mapas.

Cuando coloco el mapa en una pagina interna funciona perfectamente , pero al colocarlo en la pagina principal no funciona, no se puede realizar ninguna accion sobre el mapa y se generan estos errores.

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? GRACIAS! [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: plantilla comprada, hecha por ti o una de las que hay en el sitio de drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un API Key asignada ???, posiblemente tengas un API Key de google Maps para tu sitio local, pero debes generar una nueva con el nombre de tu dominio para que las librerias de google maps funcionen correctamente.

Usando una cuenta de google, puedes obtener una API Key nueva desde https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=es-419.